# IBM Sterling Connect:Direct and encryption

Tags: ibm-sterling

Does anyone know if the base Connect:Direct protocol ( used between two IBM Sterling secure proxy instances) supports encryption ? Or do you need to enable the Secure+ extension to obtain this feature ?

Thanks,
Ranjit

Answer (score 0):

Connect Direct itself is secure, as no node without having the right information (IP AND NODE NAME) can access. 
However the security for data streamed enroute should be done  using  Secure plus which involves certificate - implementing it would be a viable solution so long as traffic passes over internet and different datacenters.